# Go to error line in MATLAB command window

Tags: matlab

In Python's Spyder, I'd click on `temp_fn` below and be taken directly to the offending line.

Instead, it opens a box, and the closest is `View code for temp_fn.m`, but that goes to top of the function, not the offending line.

Is there anything better for achieving said functionality? Just use that box and then `Ctrl + D` (go-to line)? Note it must work for any level of stack trace, not just the final offending line.

[image]

Comment: This is the 2nd question where you've later added a comment saying the MATLAB IDE is flawed for something when in fact it does do exactly what you want, which at best is confusing - you're welcome to use another language, or log a feature request with MathWorks directly (for what it's worth, I didn't downvote, just commenting)

Comment: The comment responds to people being offended by the image. In-place assignment has nothing to do with IDE. MATLAB being bad for programming isn't news, and some features people have been asking for years. QoL doesn't earn money.

Comment: And I'm aware it's not just engineers lazing around... but they could perhaps poke the executives/whoever a bit harder. Anyway it's just a sentiment not directed at anyone in particular. Someone also complained of OOP (crack at Python), I didn't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on `line 5`, it's a hyperlink to the line within `temp_fn`.

For the previous level of the stack trace, click the `line 4` hyperlink to the line within `temp` in this example.